# Error importing and merging text files with read.table() or read.csv()

Tags: r

I'm trying to import a large number of text files and merge them into a single datatable using the script below, so I can parse the text .  The files were originally eml files so the formatting is a mess.  I'm not interested in separating the text into fields, it would be perfectly fine if the datatable only had one field with all the text from the files in it.  When I run the script below I keep getting the following error.

```
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

I've tried setting sep= various things or running it without it, but it still gives the same error.  I've also tried running the same code except replacing read.table with read.csv, but again I get the same error.  Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
setwd("~/stuff/folder")
file_list <- list.files()
for (file in file_list){
  # if the merged dataset doesn't exist, create it
  if (!exists("dataset")){
    dataset <- read.table(file, header=FALSE,fill=TRUE,comment.char="",strip.white = TRUE)
  }
  # if the merged dataset does exist, append to it
  if (exists("dataset")){
    temp_dataset <-read.table(file, header=FALSE,fill=TRUE,comment.char="",strip.white = TRUE)
    dataset<-rbind(dataset, temp_dataset)
    rm(temp_dataset)
  }
}
```

Comment: i'd suggest replacing the `for…` construct with `lapply` then wrapping that with either `dplyr::bind_rows`  or `data.table::rbindlist` (setting `fill=TRUE` for the latter) and assigning the result to your `dataset` variable vs build it piecemeal.

Comment: If you go with `data.table` you may find its `fread` function usefull to speed up the reading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading multiple files into R - Best practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888757/reading-multiple-files-into-r-best-practice)

Answer (score 1):

I think something lighter could work for you and may avoid this specific error:

```
them.files <- lapply(1:number.of.files,function(x) 
read.table(paste(paste("lolz",x,sep=""),'txt',sep='.')),header=FALSE,fill=TRUE,comment.char="",strip.white = TRUE)
```

Adapt the function to whatever your files names are.

**Edit:**
Actually maybe something like this could be better:

```
 them.files <- lapply(1:length(file_list),function(x) 
 read.table(file_list[x],header=FALSE,fill=TRUE,comment.char="",strip.white = TRUE)
```

Merging step:

```
everyday.Im.merging <- do.call(rbind,them.files)
```

I am sure there are beautiful ways to do it with `dplyr` or `data.table` but I am a caveman.

If I may add something, I would also fancy a checking step prior the previous line of code:

```
sapply(them.files,str)
```

Comment: Thanks Ouistiti, I tried your suggestion but it still threw the same error.  Then I found smartbind from gtools and that did the trick.

Comment: You may want to answer your own question.