# How to merge data from several Excel sheets in several Excel files in a folder?

Tags: r

I did some research on this before posting and I came up with this script (which doesn't work):

```
library(gdata)
setwd("C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/excel_files")
data.files = list.files(pattern = "*.xls") 

files<-data.files

#get list of files
data.to.merge <- lapply(files, read.xls) #read in files using lapply
```

After the data.to.merge, I get this error:

> Error in findPerl(verbose = verbose) :

How can I get this to work?

Comment: That's not the whole error message.  What's the rest?

Comment: You might want to try another package for reading `xls`-files. For some inspiration see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32888918/2204410).

Comment: Thanks a lot guys!!  The code below will read the first sheet in all the files.

However, I want to read all sheets in all files and merge everything.

Comment: library(readxl)
    setwd("C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/excel_files")
    file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xls')
    df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer will depend on how you want your data to look. If you use lapply, you'll get a list.

```
library(xlsx)
setwd("C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/excel_files")
data.files = list.files(pattern = "*.xls")
data <- lapply(data.files, function(x) read.xlsx(x, sheetIndex = 1))
```

If you want to merge your data into a single data frame (for example, if your files all have the same format, I would suggest a for-loop

```
for (i in file.list) {
    data <- rbind(data, read.xlsx(i, sheetIndex = 1))
}
```

You can swap out `rbind` for `merge` depending on the contents of your files.