# rbind multiple data frames without typing out all the names of the data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

Have 68 data frames with the same structure and columns. I started to use `rbind` and after typing in about 30 df names, I thought there might be an easier way to concatenate all the data frames without typing in each name. I mean, what if you have 100,000 data frames to concatenate? I looked at a dozen of online resources including this site and didn't find exactly what I was looking for.

All the 68 data frames are named sequentially. For example: `df_01`, `df_02`, ... up to `df_68`. I tried to do `rbind(df_01:df_68)` and of course this did not work.

Comment: Put the names in a list and then bind them together. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888757/reading-multiple-files-into-r-best-practice/32888918#32888918) can help you.

Comment: Also `do.call("rbind", mget(sprintf("df_%02d", 1:5)))`.

Comment: How did you wind up with all those data.frames? It seems like you might not be doing things "The R Way." R is different than SAS.

Comment: I downloaded bunch of text files from a government site. Had I thought of combining the text files into one before importing into R, it would have been easier