# R - Adding filepath to each row of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, filepath

I am relatively new to R and I am working on creating one dataframe out of many .csv files that I have in different subfolders of the same folder. Thus far, I've got this:

```
setwd("~/LMB/Top 6 - 2019/Juegos")

Batting.files  <- list.files(path = "~/LMB/Top 6 - 2019/Juegos/",
recursive = T, pattern=c("(statsHomeBatting.csv|statsVisitorBatting.csv)", 
                                       full.names=T))

setwd("~/LMB/Top 6 - 2019/Juegos/")

Batting.Logs <- do.call(rbind,lapply(Batting.files,read.csv, check.names = FALSE, sep = ";"))
```

The subfolders where I have the files look like this:

```
~\LMB\Top 6 - 2019\Juegos\Lanús at Ferro Feb 10
```

What I'd like is to have a variable in each column (let's name it `Batting.Logs$Game` where it shows the last part of the directory (in this case `Lanús at Ferro Feb 10`)

I have searched through old answers but I have not been able to get it done, so I am now unsure that it can be done with the current coding I have.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you combine this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44304004/3438524 (to the question: [Read multiple csv data and create new columns at one time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302912/read-multiple-csv-data-and-create-new-columns-at-one-time))

with dirname and basename (as already npjc posted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54888162/3438524), this should do the trick.

```
Batting.files  <- list.files(path = "~/LMB/Top 6 - 2019/Juegos/",
    recursive = T, pattern=c("(statsHomeBatting.csv|statsVisitorBatting.csv)", 
                                           full.names=T))
dt.list <- sapply(file.list, fread, simplify=FALSE,data.table=F)
DT <- rbindlist(dt.list, idcol = 'folder')[, `:=` (folder = basename(dirname(folder)))]
```

Comment: Hi @user3438524 Sorry for the basic question, but I've read the help regarding both `rbindlist` and `dirname`, as I am not familiar with them, but I'm having an issue with the last line of code, where if a put my directory in `basename(dirname(*folder*))`, I get the following

*Cannot use := to add columns to a null data.table (no columns), currently*

On the contrary, if I simply leave `folder`, I get:

*Error in dirname(folder) : object 'folder' not found*

I appreciate your help

Comment: Hi @Eliseo Avramides,

What R is telling you (when you leave folder - without asterisks) is that the variable folder do not exists (which is the name of your new data.frame column, where the path is stored). 

Did you left the idcol = 'folder'' in the last row?
Try with str(DT) to get an idea of the structure of your object (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/str.html). What is the name of your first column?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I struggled a little bit (not this much, it was just that I was on holiday) but I ended up nailing it like this

`dt.list.Batting <- sapply(Batting.files, fread, simplify=FALSE)

Batting.by.Game <- rbindlist(dt.list.Batting, idcol = "id")[, `:=` (Game = basename(dirname(id)))]`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `?dirname()` and `?basename()`.

> `dirname(path)` returns the part of the path up to but excluding the last path separator, or "." if there is no path separator.
>
> `basename(path)` removes all of the path up to and including the last path separator (if any).

#### example:

A data frame with two paths, to get the immediate parent directory, first extract the directory name then extract the basename of the result.

```r
d <- data.frame(path = c('path/to/some/file.csv', 'path/to/another/file.csv'),
                stringsAsFactors = F)

d$file_dir <- basename(dirname(d$path))

d

#>                       path file_dir
#> 1    path/to/some/file.csv     some
#> 2 path/to/another/file.csv  another
```