# Read CSV and create data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to save the following commands in a shorter way so that each time I do not repeat the same actions.

```
aa <- read_excel("C:/Users/Piotr/Desktop/aa.xlsx")
bb <- read_excel("C:/Users/Piotr/Desktop/bb.xlsx")

data=as.data.frame(aa[1:100,c(1, 18, 20, 22, 35, 39, 41, 44)])
row.names(data) <- data$Player
data=data[,-1]

data2=as.data.frame(bb[1:100,c(1, 18, 20, 22, 35, 39, 41, 44)])
row.names(data2) <- data2$Player
data2=data2[,-1]

data_sets <- c("data","data2")
```

Comment: You can either use a loop (like `lapply`) or write a function or do both. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I would like to learn this simplest way.

Comment: Some inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32888757/2204410

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As docendo suggested, just generalize your repeated steps into a function:

```
clean_data <- function(x) {

data <- read_excel(paste0("C:/Users/Piotr/Desktop/", x, ".xlsx"))
data=as.data.frame(data[1:100,c(1, 18, 20, 22, 35, 39, 41, 44)])
  row.names(data) <- data$Player
  data=data[,-1]
return(data)
}

data_sets = c(clean_data("aa"), clean_data("bb"))
names(data_sets) = c("data", "data2")
```

Comment: In my above example the result is this: >   data_sets=c("data","data2")
> data_sets
[1] "data"  "data2"