# Merging data from approx. 70 tables in R

Tags: r, excel

I have country-by-country reports of 10 diffrent companies over a time frame of 7 years (70 tables of excel data). I am not really good or creative in formating information in a user friendly way. How can I illustrate develompments of certain ratios from each company over the 7 years and as well illustrate the development of that ratio averaged over all the 10 companies?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: The situation is as follows: I have 10 firms and for all those firms I have a table structred by country. So I have for year 1 a table of company "i" with their number of employees, turnover, taxes paid.... I have to organize the countries into 3 categories (e.g. small, med, large). Then I have to compute the share of company i's employees per categorie.  Afterwards, I need to illustrate the development of these ratios over those 7 years for each company as well as averaged over the companies.
Sry for this messy explenation. But I think I can't merge this data into 1(mix diffrent years/compan

Answer (score 1):

Since you give only little infromation and no R code it is hard to help specificly. To first load in your Excel files, since you have many, read the following:
[How can I read multiple (excel) files into R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888757/how-can-i-read-multiple-excel-files-into-r)

Then to merge the data frames: [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right?rq=1) Here multiple solutions are given.
I hope the links help with your problem.