# Importing several files from different subfolders

Tags: r, import, directory

I hope you can help me here, I would like to import several files stored in several folders and subfolders. Until now I either copy/pasted the results in one excel file or imported one file after another in R, but now I have to many files to deal with...

Here is what I need to do:
1 folder: Data
--> containing 60 subfolders with subject ID: subj 1, subj 2, subj 3, ...
--> each subfolders contained 6 excel files: T1, T2,t3,....

I would like to import all these excels files in R, either in one big data frame or one data frame for each subject. And even better would be to add a column with "Subject ID" (Subj1, subj2, subj3,...) and another one with Lap (T1, T2, T3....).

Does someone know how to do that?
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read multiple (excel) files into R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888757/how-can-i-read-multiple-excel-files-into-r)

Comment: No because in this question, all the excel files are in the same folder, and I have different folder with several excel files in each of them...

Comment: Yes, because you write a function to import all the files in one folder and then loop through all the folders of interest.

Comment: Ok ,I checked again, not sure I understand everything but I manage to do something actually. Thanks! Could you maybe just help me with where to add that I like to skip the first 2 rows in each excel file?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> lapply(list.files(path="./folder/",pattern='subj', recursive=T),FUN=function(x) load(file=paste0("./folder/",x),.GlobalEnv))
> ```

It is not really clear the structure of your folder/subfolder/files, but I think these lapply function will help you. You have to specify the `path`, the `pattern`, and if you want it to look inside the subfolder (`recursive`). Then a `function` will load them all (in that case you have to specify a `function` that reads the type of file you want (e.g. `load("...Rdata")`, `read.csv()`, etc)

Comment: I manage something like that: file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.CSV', recursive = TRUE)
file.list <- setNames(file.list, file.list)
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_csv, skip=2)
TTP <- bind_rows(df.list, .id = "id")    But the separator is ";" and I don't know where to specify it, for now I have all the data in 1 column....